# What is a good way to mark that a ASP.NET custom control requires JS libraries

Tags: javascript, asp.net, custom-controls

As the question says, I am developing a custom asp.net control and I need to let the user know somehow that it needs a couple of JS libraries to be referenced on the page.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You do not have documentation for the control?

Comment: I would prefer to have some sort of javascript run that will check whether the libraries are there on load and have a popup message come up. Lot of times people (including myself) start using control right away without reading documentation if the control is intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for the existence of the required libraries once the DOM is fully loaded:

```
function init() {
    if(!jQuery) {
        alert('This control requires jQuery');
    }
}

window.onload = init;
```

The above code will give you the idea. Modify to suit your needs.

Comment: In my opinion this is the best answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Comments
2. Create a nuget package with your asp.net control and the required JavaScript libraries.

I'd vote for the second option but I also heavily use nuget.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answers but they dont really suit me. User of my control is not going to read the comments in my code and I do not want to bring in another variable (nuget) into the equation.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio nuget becomes the method for getting your user control, obviously this method works best if you are in a corporate environment with a local nuget server.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest anything other than documentation but if you really need it, you can check for the dependency JS object with another script in the header (after where the dependency JS should be inserted) and alert the user accordingly. Such as;

```
if (typeof someDependencyObject === 'undefined')
{
    alert("someDependencyObject is required with SomeASP-NET Control.");
}
```

BUT a better way would be to register your own script within your custom control code with `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

```
<script runat="server">
    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String jsName = "MyCustomScript";
        Type type = this.GetType();

        // Register the script if not already registered.
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(type, jsName))
        {
            StringBuilder js = new StringBuilder();
            js.Append("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            js.Append("function someFunc() {  } ");
            js.Append("</script>");
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(type, jsName, js.ToString());
        }
    }
</script>
```

See [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx).

Comment: It should be `typeof someDependencyObject === "undefined"`